# Как подгрузить изображение динамически в React native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Есть объект, в котором есть определенное количество ссылок на изображения. Мне нужно их подключить в React Native. Но проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь циклом пройтись по объекту и подключить картинки, то выбивает ошибку.

Пример объекта:

```js
var data = [{
photo: 'http://mignews.com.ua/modules/news/images/articles/changing/14869199-vsemirnyj-den-kotov-foto.jpg',
  },
  {
photo: 'http://www.zoovet.ru/images/cats_clich.jpg',
  },
  {
photo: 'http://cat-lifes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/smeshnye-kartinki-tancuyushhix-kotov-4.jpeg',
  },
]
```

Пример того как я пробовал решить в (React Native) :

```js
data.map(el =>
       <Image source={require('./images/' + el + '.png')} />
 );
```

Пример решения подобной задачи для браузера (в React Native нужен такой же результат):

```js
var data = [{
    photo: 'http://mignews.com.ua/modules/news/images/articles/changing/14869199-vsemirnyj-den-kotov-foto.jpg',
  },
  {
    photo: 'http://www.zoovet.ru/images/cats_clich.jpg',
  },
  {
    photo: 'http://cat-lifes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/smeshnye-kartinki-tancuyushhix-kotov-4.jpeg',
  },
]

data.map(el =>
  $('.image').append("<img src=" + el.photo + "  />")
);
```

```html
<div class='image'> </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Нужно циклом пройтись по объекту и подключить картинки, которые лежат по указанному пути в объекте. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Что именно необходимо?  Что Вы хотите получить? В данной формулировке непонятно в какую сторону копать, т.к не ясна цель.

Comment: @VAndrJ, Поправил вопрос. Нужно лишь подгрузить изображения в React Native, при помощи цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда для Вас плохие новости. В документации по Image указано:

> In order for this to work, the image name in `require` has to be known statically.

(Чтобы работало, название картинки **должно** быть задано статически). И плохой пример оттуда же:

```
// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />
```

Но если хотите именно вот так, тогда поместите картинки в `Images.xcassets` и используйте uri. Вы пытаетесь так:

```
<Image source={require('./images/' + el + '.png')} />
```

А нужно будет так:

```
<Image source={{uri: el}} />
```