# Как в React подключить динамический импорт картинки?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, импорт

При написании очередного компонента, React удивил тем, что динамически не может дотягивать ссылки. 
Требует явный статический путь

```
import image from "../../../resources/images/harry_potter_1_fil_stone.jpg"
```

Гуглил, но поиски дали только неработающие решения вперемешку с webpack. Есть альтернатива?

p.s. Эта ссылка
[Как подгрузить изображение динамически в React native?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685489/) мне непонятная. Может быть решение и рабочее.

Comment: Тут бы еще понять какую именно "динамику" хочешь получить... Картинки ведь не обязательно держать в самом проекте. Можно использовать любой УРЛ, по которому картинка будет доступна на клиенте.

Comment: Вот еще ряд ответов как можно использовать картинки в Реакт - https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.7b549d5d-64ac69cb-6225a4b6-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот это [решение](https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/react-webpack-lazy-loading) с webpack и babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import. На примере [live-demo](https://rubenspgcavalcante.github.io/react-webpack-lazy-loading/) можно увидеть что динамический импорт компонентов работает, так что с изображениями проблем не должно возникнуть.